# Set up Socket.IO to run on Node Windows

Tags: node.js, socket.io, dependencies, npm-install

I am new to programming and  I am doing the WebRTC codelab here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#6

I am at the part titled "**Set up Socket.IO to run on Node**" where it says "To install dependencies, run the following from the command line terminal in your work directory:

npm install", however, when I type npm install the command prompt in Windows, it does not recognize the command. I feel like this should be pretty easy, so am I missing something?

---

Set up Socket.IO to run on Node
For this and the following steps, you'll run Socket.IO on Node.

At the top level of your work directory create a file named package.json with the following contents:

{
  "name": "webrtc-codelab",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "WebRTC codelab",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-static": "0.7.7",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0"
  }
}
This is an app manifest that tells Node Package Manager (npm) what project dependencies to install.

To install dependencies, run the following from the command line terminal in your work directory:

npm install
You should see an installation log that ends something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX3US.png)

Comment: Install node.js and set the path. It will automatically install npm for you

Comment: Thanks! So apparently I had to use the node console and that helped. Not sure if you can use the regular Windows command prompt as well?

Comment: No, you still need to use the windows command prompt (optional bash terminal) but, to run Node.js command on your prompt you need to install it.